# Display Content Result Text from AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an `Ajax.Action` link hooked up to a post method in my controller class that returns a `ContentResult`.  I'm able to make the request and get the response just fine when looking in a tool like firebug, but I'm having problems trying to actually access or do anything with the response text.

Basically, I have something like this in my controller:

```
public ContentResult RevertToDefault(int id, string default)
{
  /** Update the DB **/

  return Content(default);
}
```

And this in my view:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
  "Revert",
  "RevertToDefault",
  new { id = Model.MyObject.ID, default = Model.MyObject.DefaultValue },
  new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "function(r) { alert(r); }" })%>
```

Right now, the alert just returns `[object Object]`.  The change is made in the database, and I'm guessing that I have access to the `ContentResult` somewhere in that `r` object, but I'm having a hard time finding good examples/documentation online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the previous answer is absolutely correct. Just do this:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(
  "Revert",
  "RevertToDefault",
  new { id = Model.MyObject.ID, default = Model.MyObject.DefaultValue },
  new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "function(r) { alert(r.get_data()); }" })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the argument to the OnComplete event handler is an ajaxContext, so you could try ajaxContext.get_response() and get your response object or ajaxContext.get_data(), which should return the actual data sent as response.